# Loading TravisCI encrypted environment variables in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, continuous-integration

I'm developing a Java SDK for an HTTP API. The SDK is open source and I'd like to add automated Travis tests. However, the API requires an API key for authentication and there isn't one that can be added as plain text in the unit tests. Travis allows for environment variables to be encrypted, so I want to add the API key in it's encrypted form to the project. How can I load the value of this encrypted variable in my JUnit files, decrypt it, and run the tests?